# Multiple Query String Items in crontab Job

Tags: cron

I have the following cron job command:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/lynx -term=vt100 http://abc.com/dir1/di2/script.php?action=add&config=xyz >/dev/null 2>&1
```

My PHP script does not recognize _GET['config'] and I get a "Cron Daemon" email message which seems to alert me that the crontab instruction is not correct.

If I take out the 2nd _GET var I do not get the "Cron Daemon" email.

Any thoughts or suggestions on how to define multiple query string items in a crontab job?

BTW, I tried the URL Encode char for the ampersand and that did not work either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try putting your url in quotes :

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/lynx -term=vt100 "http://abc.com/dir1/di2/script.php?action=add&config=xyz" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

For the little explanation, `&` is a special character which put the process in the background, so you have to put the url in quotes, otherwise cron try to put the first part in the background and execute the second part.

Comment: Ah, didn't know I could do that...I'll try and post back

Comment: I was unaware you could/should use quotes to surround blocks of text in a cron job instruction